# Updating props array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array object that is passed to my component and avalaible through @props.

```
console.log ( @props.users.pages )
> [ ["Tada", "A"], ["Todo", "B"] ]
```

Actually, I want to append something to it (a new array).

What do you recommend beside this:

```
function add(){
  var arr = Array();
  arr.push("Toto", "C");
  @props.users.pages.push( arr );
  @forceUpdate()
}
```

The result after calling add() should be:

```
console.log ( @props.users.pages )
> [ ["Tada", "A"], ["Todo", "B"], ["Toto", "C" ]
```

The biggest problem here is that arr can be destroyed by the garbage collector since it's only local and I would prefer to use @setProps instead of forcing updates manually.

Comment: You should write `var arr` to give it a local scope, but in any case after `@props.users.pages.push( arr );` it is referenced by another object is is not GCed.

Comment: Yes sorry I edited my post. It's var arr that i have

Comment: A component shouldn't edit its props. The `add` function should call a method on the parent component, and the parent component should edit the users array that it is passing as a prop.

Comment: Yes it's seems to be better :=) ty

Answer (score 1):

Remember what's the doc says:

> So far, each component has rendered itself once based on its props. props are immutable: they are passed from the parent and are "owned" by the parent.

See it here [Reactive state](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#reactive-state).